# Accessing TListItem.Data leads to an error when using records

Tags: delphi, record, tlistview

I have a program which uses `TListView` to visualize and store some data. `TListitem`'s data property is filled with a pointer to a record like so:

```
type
  TWatch = record
    name : string;
    path : string;
    //...
end;

procedure TfrmProcessWatcherMain.AddWatchToListView(AWatch: TWatch);
var
  ANewWatch : TListItem;
begin
  ANewWatch := lvWatches.Items.Add; //lvWatches is TListview
  //...
  ANewWatch.Data:= @AWatch;
end;
```

When I'm trying to retrieve this data somehow I'm getting access violation error, which is a total surprise for me because all seems legit, here is code of retrieval:

```
if(lvWatches.Selected <> nil) then begin
  tempWatch := TWatch(lvWatches.Selected.Data^); // AV here
  ShowMessage(tempWatch.name);
```

Also `AWatch` which is passed to a first function is stored in a

```
WatchList : TList<TWatch>;
```

so it is accessible using other methods

Comment: Local variable `ANewWatch` and associated data unavailable outside `AddWatchToListView`. Use dynamically allocated  pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `@AWatch` is the address of a local variable. As soon as `AddWatchToListView` returns `AWatch` goes out of scope and that address is no longer valid.

Instead of taking the address of a local variable you need to allocate a record on the heap using `New`.

```
procedure TfrmProcessWatcherMain.AddWatchToListView(AWatch: TWatch);
var
  ANewWatch : TListItem;
  P : ^TWatch;
begin
  ANewWatch := lvWatches.Items.Add;
  New(P);
  P^ := AWatch;
  ANewWatch.Data:= P;
end;
```

You will need to deallocate the memory with `Dispose` whenever a list item is destroyed. Do that using the list view's `OnDeletion` event.

Alternatively, you could store the index of the item in `WatchList`. Or the address of the record in `WatchList`, which you get like this: `@WatchList.List[Index]`. Both of these options rely on `WatchList` not being modified after references to items are taken, which may be too constraining for you.

Comment: Why not using pointers to items in `WatchList`, which already has allocated records?

Comment: @LURD You could do that, provided that WatchList is not modified after a ref was taken.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that function parameters is passed by reference not instantinating new local variable, so `AWatch` is not a local var but a reference to a list item. As for `@WatchList.List[Index]` it would be easier but you can not use pointer to a property, so I've used WatchList index as a reference `AddWatchToListView(AWatch: TWatch; WatchIndex : integer);`

Comment: `AWatch` is a by value parameter, which makes it a local variable.  It's not passed by reference. That's because records are value types and not reference types. I suspect that's your fundamental mis-think.  `TList<T>.List` is a dynamic array. `@WatchList.List[Index]` is the way to take a reference to the internal member of the list. No use if you modify the list after taking a reference though. So probably no recommended.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'm using classes in most so I've forgot about that.

I've just realised that I don't have a `List` field in my `TList`, don't know why, maybe not that version, or something is not included in uses list? I'm using XE2, btw. Earlier I thought that you mean Items.
As for the modifications, when i change watchlist listview is also changed so it rely on actual information

Comment: That was added in XE3 when Emba realised that there was no way to access the underlying member

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your help, then I'll continue to use Index for now.

Comment: That will work well so long as you never insert a new item in front of one that you have referenced.